# transfer value from client to server side node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, pug

Tried lots of examples, spend lots of hours but it just didn't work out. It would be great if someone could help me in this situation. So, what I want to do is to get value from                 `p#lessonText.lesson(style='margin-left:1%;' name='desc') #{item.description}` 
I need that `#{item.description}` to be passed to my server side.

This is my client code

```
form#myForm()
  .container
    ul
      each item, index in items
        #allLessons.container
          .lessonsWrap
            h3.lesson #{index+1} . Lesson |
            p#lessonText.lesson(style='margin-left:1%;' name='desc') #{item.description}
            button#butPam.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Begin
            .lesDescription
              p(style='margin-left:1%;') Lecturer: #{item.author}
              p(style='margin-left:1%;') Level: #{item.level}

              script.
                $('#myForm').on('submit', function(event){

                  var createVar = $('#lessonText').text();
                  alert(createVar);
                  $.ajax({
                    url: '/qVal',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({desc: createVar.val()}),
                    async: true,
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);

                    }
                  })

                });
```

Here in server side for now I just want to see, if I can create a variable, which is passed from client side.

```
router.post('/qVal', function(req,res){
     console.log("server");
     var description = req.body.desc; 
     console.log(typeof(desc));
     console.log(desc);
});
```

Maybe I'm using wrong method, maybe I should use GET method for this?
Its important to say, that it looks my router.post doesn't work. When I write console.log("server"), in the console word "server" isn't appearing.

Comment: So is your `console.log("server");` getting fired?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't

Comment: Check your browser's network tab of the ajax call is firing at all, and check the URL in the request. I'm guessing there might be an issue with the /qVal path

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/VDpIGOG.png and url http://i.imgur.com/yM0l67T.png . Any thoughts?

Comment: The createVar.val() statement is invalid since you're already doing var createVar = $('#lessonText').text().

Comment: Tried now to write only var createVar = $('#lessonText'); but problem still persists. Now I'm getting bunch of errors http://i.imgur.com/sOKKnx9.png

Comment: Looks like your `qVal` event is getting fired now. Remove the `JSON.stringify` from ajax and send the data directly like `data: {desc: createVar.val()},`

Comment: Already done that, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
var querystring = require('querystring');

router.post('/qVal', function(req,res){
     req.on('data',function(data){
          data = querystring.parse(data.toString('utf-8'));
          var description = data.desc; 
          console.log(typeof(desc));
          console.log(desc);
     });
}
```

Comment: It looks like router.post isn't firing up

Comment: Need more piece of code to understand else visit my github repo  https://github.com/SaifAnsari96/Rest-Server-with-pure-Node.js/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score 0):

You doing the wrong method to send data front to the server, on your data section you convert JSON to string, but on the server, you get JSON value that's the reason what I see.

**Front End Ajax Request**

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/qVal',
                    method: 'post',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: {desc: createVar.val()},
                    async: true,
                    success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                  })
```

**Node Js**

```
router.post('/qVal', function(req,res){
     console.log("server");
     console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
     console.log(req.body.desc)
}
```

Comment: It looks like router.post isn't firing up. Console doesn't show "server"

Answer (score 0):

When you using `JSON.stringify` it's parse your `JSON` to String, if it's have  `" "`

If you will add `"desc"` like this :
**Client**

```
$.ajax({
         url: '/qVal',
         method: 'post',
         data: {
                    "desc": createVar.val()
                },
         async: true,
         success: function(response){
         console.log(response);
         }
      })
```

**Server**

```
router.post('/qVal', function(req, res){
         console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
         console.log(req.body.desc)
}
```

it will send in the right way to the server.

Comment: Did everything as you said but this is what I get. http://i.imgur.com/KQJhiwa.png It looks like I'm getting 6 empty values from client

Comment: maybe you passing empty value, try to send "desc" : "example", if it's works, then what you sending is incorrectly bad

Comment: Hmmm, if I write something random, for example,  `data: {"desc": "test"},` it works and I get string with a name "test" in my server side. So, then maybe you know how can i pass value from any tag like h2, p or any other?

Comment: So this is a different question, mark this one as answered, and ask other question @SimonDraymon